# Why doesn't this regex work with Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Trying to to match the hash character fails, but succeeds for any other member 
of the regex.

Why does this fail?

Thanks,

Joe

```
UNIT = [ 'floor', 'fl', '#', 'penthouse', 'mezzanine', 'basement', 'room' ]

unit_regex = "\\b(" + UNIT.to_a.join("|") + ")\\b"

unit_regexp = Regexp.new(unit_regex, Regexp::IGNORECASE)

x=unit_regexp.match('#')
```

Comment: Your real problem what "word boundary" means, it roughly means "a word character on one side and nothing or a non-word character on the other side" but `#` is not a word character. I think you're going to have to be a little more explicit in your regex as to what you're trying to match.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments, your problem is that `\b` is a word boundary inside a regex (unless it is inside a character class, sigh, the `\b` in `/[\b]/` is a backspace just like in a double quoted string). A word boundary is roughly

> a word character on one side and nothing or a non-word character on the other side

But `#` is not a word character so `/\b/` can't match `'#'` at all and your whole regex fails to match.

You're going to have to be more explicit about what you're trying to match. A first stab would be "the beginning of the string or whitespace" instead of the first `\b` and "the end of the string or whitespace" instead of the second `\b`. That could be expressed like this:

```
unit_regex = '(?<=\A|\s)(' + UNIT.to_a.join('|') + ')(?=\z|\s)'
```

Note that I've switched to single quotes to avoid all the double escaping hassles. The `?<=` is a *positive lookbehind*, that means that `(\A|\s)` needs to be there but it won't be matched by the expression; similarly, `?=` is a *positive lookahead*. See [the manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors) for more details. Also note that we're using `\A` rather than `^` since `^` matches the beginning of a *line* not the *string*; similarly, `\z` instead of `$` because `\z` matches the end of the *string* whereas `$` matches the end of a *line*.

You may need to tweak the regex depending on your data but hopefully that will get you started.

Comment: Thank you all. I completely missed the word boundary issue.